# Android SQLite cursor getType appears to be crashing app

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

When inserting temporary values to all of the columns in my table it appears to work.  See method below and log below.  But when I test if the column exists with my test method below, it returns a false that the column exists!!

Also you can see in the log that the getType is returning 0 for the columns except the name column??!!  For this reason I added the table creation method at the bottom (and, yes, I updated the version number)

Note that this question has been edited based on comments below (so the first couple comments may not make sense).

This first snippet of code is from where the two methods below are called

```
ContentValues values = setContVal_All_Columns(myTable);

//create row
long insertId = database.insert(myTable, null, values);
System.out.println("Column date exists = " + String.valueOf(doesColumnExist(myTable,"date")));
```

setContVal_All_Columns Method:

```
//sets generic content values to initialize row = excluding ID column
private ContentValues setContVal_All_Columns(String myTable) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(myTable,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    for(String name : columnNames) {
        if(!name.equals(IdColumn)) {  //excludes Id column
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(name);
            System.out.println("Column name = " + name + " index = " + String.valueOf(index));
            System.out.println("Type = " + String.valueOf(cursor.getType(index))); //appears to crash on the getType
            if (cursor.getType(index) == 3) {  //String
                System.out.println("Column is string");
                contentValues.put(name, " ");
            } else if (cursor.getType(index) == 1) {  //integer
                contentValues.put(name, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    return contentValues;
}
```

LOG INFO:

```
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = date index = 1
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = name index = 2
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 3
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column is string
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = altitude index = 3
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = is_used index = 4
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = warning index = 5
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = action index = 6
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.316    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column date exists = false
```

EDIT: METHOD FOR TESTING IF COLUMN EXISTS: always returning -1 on date column...

```
private boolean doesColumnExist(String myTable, String myColumn) {
    boolean doesExist = true;

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(" + myTable + ")",null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int value = cursor.getColumnIndex(myColumn);

if(value == -1)
{
    doesExist = false;
}
return doesExist;
}
```

EDIT: Table Creation Method:

```
//Database creation sql statement
private static final String SQL_CREATE_SPECIAL_DAYS =
        "CREATE TABLE " + dbFields.TABLE_NAME_SPECIAL_DAYS + " (" +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ID + INTEGER_PRIMARY_KEY + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_DATE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ALTITUDE + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_USED + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_WARNING + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ACTION + INTEGER_TYPE +
                // Any other options for the CREATE command
                " )";



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_SPECIAL_DAYS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbFields.TABLE_NAME_SPECIAL_DAYS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: show crash log and in which line app crashing?

Comment: Does the update give the log info requested?

Comment: and what google returns for: *Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1* ?

Comment: I noticed that line, but don't know what it means.  FYI - When I use getColumnIndex on my date column that has not yet been give a value, it returns -1 even though it is definitely in the table.  Not sure if that helps unwrap this mystery.  Note that the index in the Log for the "date" column says 1, not -1.  I'm am so lost.

Comment: Simplify the problem by removing the getType()  from the print. Put it on a line by itself. If you still get an error, make sure that it has the same stack trace as what you posted.

Comment: I put it in the print because I wanted to verify that it was what was throwing the error.  And it seems to be so since it prints the line before it (see Log) but not the line with the getType

Comment: MikeWallace - I ran it commenting out.... System.out.println("Type = " + String.valueOf(cursor.getType(index)));  .... appears to be the same stacktrace, presumably from the getType a couple lines below

Comment: @EdwardBagby : try calling `cursor.moveToFirst()` after the line `String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();`

Comment: Yes.  some progress.  it worked on the method above. Thanks Squonk.. but I'm not sure it solved the larger issue.  I test the column after with a cursor.getColumnIndex(myColumn) and it gives me -1 column index!  I even used your cursor.moveToFirst(); beforehand.  I added the test method to my question.

Comment: You've actually got two questions here and should really ask another separate question for your column index problem although I can tell you it won't work using `PRAGMA table_info(...)` - there's no reason it shouldn't work in your original code using the usual `cursor.getColumnIndex(...)` method.

Comment: I see your point, but I'm guessing that the -1 on getColumnIndex and the getType 0 are related...  Any ideas where to go from here.  I'll ask another question if that's my only recourse

Comment: I'll post an answer as to why `getType()` was causing a problem and explain why. Give me a few minutes...

Comment: Thanks @Squonk... I'm now writing a separate question for the method returning false on testing if the column exists.  Though I think it will need to be 1-1/2 hours after my first question was asked, or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this code from your original code block...

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(myTable,null,null,null,null,null,null);
String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
```

...when performing any cursor query, the cursor 'index' (i.e., the dataset row it points to) is always -1. This is *before* rhe first row which has an index of 0 (there are reasons for this). It is, however, legal to call `getColumNames()` at this point as the column names are cataloged separately during the query process and will be held, unchanged, for the life of the cursor.

Calling `getType()`, however, does require the cursor to 'pointing at` (referencing) a valid row in the dataset. The docs aren't completely clear but infer this as a requirement...

> public abstract int getType (int columnIndex) Added in API level 11
>
> Returns data type of the given column's value. **The preferred type of the column is returned but the data may be converted to other types as documented in the get-type methods such as getInt(int), getFloat(int) etc.**

In other words, unless the cursor is referencing a valid row of the dataset, it's not possible to get the *preferred* type. Simply moving the cursor to the first row (assuming it has valid data rows in the dataset) allows getting the preferred type of the actual data in each column.

So basically just add `moveToFirst()` before using `getType()`...

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(myTable,null,null,null,null,null,null);
String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
    cursor.moveToFirst(); // Calls to cursor.getType() will work from now on
```

Comment: Good clear answer as to why the original crashing.  Makes sense.  Any idea why they getType is returning 0 now that I've included cursor.moveToFirst() ??

Comment: Also - if you have any ideas for the next question, I'm all ears:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554774/android-sqlite-returning-1-with-getcolumnindex-when-column-obviously-exists

Comment: @EdwardBagby : The value 0 indicates `Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL` which suggests just that, i.e., there's a 'null' dat value in the column.

Comment: Are you saying that the getType reads the type of the actual value, and not the data type assigned to the column?

Comment: @EdwardBagby : Yes. That's why it needs a valid row in the dataset. For example, 'null' isn't a valid data type for a table column but the value might be null (if allowed). SQLite will also allow putting different data types into columns they're not supposed to go into (for instance writing 1 instead of "1" into a String column is allowed). It seems the `getType()` method is a little vague - the docs certainly are as they suggest it will return the "preferred" type and yet it seems to return the actual type if different.

Comment: Ahhh... So different from Access databases.  Thank you.  And it doesn't hurt to have vague documentation.  Keeps us talking :)