# Android SQlite returning -1 with getColumnIndex when column obviously exists

Tags: android, sqlite

When inserting temporary values to all of the columns in my table, it appears to work.  See method below and log below.  But when I test if the column exists with my test method below, it returns a false that the column exists!!

The first snippet of code shows from where the temporary values and the method for testing if a column exists is called.  The snippets below include the log, how the table is created, and the called methods.  Thank you!

```
ContentValues values = setContVal_All_Columns(myTable);

//create row
long insertId = database.insert(myTable, null, values);
System.out.println("Column date exists = " + String.valueOf(doesColumnExist(myTable,"date")));
```

setContVal_All_Columns Method:

```
//sets generic content values to initialize row = excluding ID column
private ContentValues setContVal_All_Columns(String myTable) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(myTable,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    for(String name : columnNames) {
        if(!name.equals(IdColumn)) {  //excludes Id column
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(name);
            System.out.println("Column name = " + name + " index = " + String.valueOf(index));
            System.out.println("Type = " + String.valueOf(cursor.getType(index))); //appears to crash on the getType
            if (cursor.getType(index) == 3) {  //String
                System.out.println("Column is string");
                contentValues.put(name, " ");
            } else if (cursor.getType(index) == 1) {  //integer
                contentValues.put(name, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    return contentValues;
}
```

METHOD FOR TESTING IF COLUMN EXISTS: always returning -1 on date column...

```
private boolean doesColumnExist(String myTable, String myColumn) {
    boolean doesExist = true;

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(" + myTable + ")",null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int value = cursor.getColumnIndex(myColumn);

if(value == -1)
{
    doesExist = false;
}
return doesExist;
}
```

LOG INFO:

```
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = date index = 1
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = name index = 2
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 3
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column is string
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = altitude index = 3
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = is_used index = 4
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = warning index = 5
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column name = action index = 6
02-16 19:58:42.296    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Type = 0
02-16 19:58:42.316    9711-9711/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ Column date exists = false
```

Table Creation Method:

```
//Database creation sql statement
private static final String SQL_CREATE_SPECIAL_DAYS =
        "CREATE TABLE " + dbFields.TABLE_NAME_SPECIAL_DAYS + " (" +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ID + INTEGER_PRIMARY_KEY + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_DATE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ALTITUDE + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_USED + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_WARNING + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ACTION + INTEGER_TYPE +
                // Any other options for the CREATE command
                " )";



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_SPECIAL_DAYS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbFields.TABLE_NAME_SPECIAL_DAYS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: When using `PRAGMA table_info(...)` you will get 6 columns (cid, name, type, notnull, dflt_value, pk). All of the column names in your table appear under the 'name' column. Try a SQLite browser tool of some sort to see the results yourself. :)

Comment: Do you mean an app that shows the database?  I downloaded it and cannot find the file for the life of me (I'm testing on my HTC)

Comment: A desktop app to show the database. You probably won't be able to find it on a device as it will be in private storage. Just use the desktop app to create a simple DB and table and run the `PRAGMA table_info` query and see what happens - all table column names are in a single column of the `PRAGMA table_info` dataset called 'name'.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with how I created the table?  Basically I want a table that that has the columns indicated, where each row contains all columns...  It's all coming together.

Comment: It seems odd that it's not possible to look at the actual database.  Do you know of any table creation methods that match more closely with what I want... should I add a diagram to my question?

Comment: I looked at my posted table creation method, and it seems okay, no?  My original database version only had the name and ID columns... could that be the source of the issue?  Even though I changed the version number?  Or is it that I'm using pragma, that its describing the table per av_lee's diagram?  Should I not use Pragma?

Comment: No, PRAGMA isn't the problem, most probably the problem is a syntax error in some of the SQL statements. I see that you not adding a semicolon in the end of statements: 'db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  " + dbFields.TABLE_NAME_SPECIAL_DAYS + " ;");'

Comment: lol.  I've speant about two and a half days on this problem...  it would be something if it were just a semicolon.  Isn't that always.  I posted a new question for this specific question by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
int value = cursor.getColumnIndex(myColumn);
```

You're assuming that `PRAGMA` would return all the columns in a single row. That's now how it works. From the `PRAGMA` documentation

> PRAGMA table_info returns **one row for each column** in the named table. Columns in the result set include the column name, data type, whether or not the column can be NULL, and the default value for the column.

So, your `doesColumnExist()` method should look something like

```
boolean doesExist = false;
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(" + myTable + ")",null);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")).equals(myColumn)) {
        doesExist = true;
        break;
    }
}

cursor.close();
return doesExist;
```

Also, do not forget to close your `Cursor`s.

Comment: I cut and pasted your latest edit and getting the same result

Comment: Oh, yes, got it.  We're trying to get the column "name", correct?

Comment: No, name is the column name in the resultset under which one of the rows will have the value matching your column name.

Comment: Though the "name" is giving an error: getString(int) in Cursor cannot be Applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: No, use `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"))` instead.

Comment: Okay.  the last edit returned a true.  Thank you.  You answered the question of the post. But it raised another issue that I think my database is set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

From SQLite documentation:

> PRAGMA table_info(table-name);
>   This pragma returns **one row for each column** in the named table.

So the result of your PRAGMA query looks roughly like this:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------
|cid | name     | type    | not null | dflt_value | pk |   // <-- you're trying to find your column names here, but instead they are in each of the rows
|-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | date     | text    | 1        |            | 0  |
|-------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | name     | text    | 0        |            | 0  | 
|-------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | altitude | integer | 1        |            | 0  |
|-------------------------------------------------------
  .......                                              
|-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is this an accurate depiction of my database as set up?  It looks like maybe you edited the diagram from a few moments ago?

Comment: Those are only first four columns, and yes they must be quite accurate, depending on what you mean by 'accurate'. Column names are accurate. Excuse me for extensive use of this word.

Comment: Your diagram is very clear. Thank you.  I may need to ask this in another question, but, I'm now trying to understand if my table looks that way because I'm using PRAGMA, or how I set it up in my posted table setup Method.  I really want the table to have several columns -name, date, altitude, etc - where each row item has all of the columns.